# What does "*(pointer + integer)" do in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm confused as to what a line of code does in this program:

```
int *temp = new int [cap];
int num = 0;

for(int i = name; i < number; i++)
{
 *(temp + count) = *(foo + i);
 num++;
}
```

`name`, `number`, and `foo` are global variables (`foo` being a pointer),
and `cap` is an argument.

Specifically, I don't understand this line:

```
 *(temp + count) = *(foo + i);
```

Why are there pointers to the parentheses, and what will this do?

Comment: I can't believe we don't have an appropriate duplicate for this question.

Comment: This is a pretty good first question, but I edited out lots of extraneous verbiage. Not extraneous *information*, as per your original "excuse any excess information" line; in particular, you started by saying you were confused about a *particular line* in the program, but without your "extra" information, there would have been no indication of *which* line confused you!

Comment: This is an alternative syntax to array indexing.

Answer (score 9):

```
*(temp + count) = *(foo + i);
```

The `+` operators are performing pointer arithmetic.  Adding an integer to a pointer value yields a new pointer incremented a specified number of objects past the original pointer.  For example, if `p` is a pointer to `arr[0]`, then `p+2` points to `arr[2]`.

The `*` operator *deferences* the resulting pointer, giving you the object that it points to.

In fact, the array indexing operator `[]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic, so that `A[i]` means `*(A+i)` (ignoring operator overloading). So the above line of code:

```
*(temp + count) = *(foo + i);
```

could also be written (more clearly IMHO) as:

```
temp[count] = foo[i];
```

You might want to read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly sections 4 (Pointers) and 6 (Arrays and Pointers). Most of the information is also applicable to C++.

*However*, C++ provides higher-level library interfaces that can be more robust than the low-level C equivalents. It's seldom a good idea in C++ to write code that deals directly with arrays and pointers to array elements, unless it's very low-level code and performance is critical and/or you're dealing with data structures from C code.

Answer (score 2):

In your example

```
*(temp + count) = *(foo + i);
```

is equivalent to

```
temp[count] = foo[i];
```

The expression `*(temp + count)` adds integer `count` to pointer `temp`, which gives you a pointer to element at position `count` in the array pointed to by `temp` and [dereferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) it.

Answer (score 1):

`*(temp + count) = *(foo + i)` means:

get the `temp` address, add `count` offset to it, then set value in resulting address `temp + count` to value from address `foo` with offset `i`

Better will be:

```
temp[count] = foo[i];
```

(By the way, it's a C style (except for `new`), not C++. Very bad code.)

Comment: It is an obscure way to write  temp[ count]= foo[i];

Comment: That is not "C-style" either, it is just bad.

Comment: @cwallach alternatively `count[temp] = i[foo];` and other combinations :)

Comment: It's just pointer math.  Doesn't count[temp] end up being `count + temp` which could be considered a run-time efficiency  improvement?  Not that it's horribly important.  Code is ugly, not sure I'd call it bad though.

Comment: @user3164339: If `*(count + temp)` is more efficient than `count[temp]`, you need to get a better compiler. The two expressions are equivalent by definition, and any decent compiler should generate equivalent code for both.

Comment: @Kevin: Right, because the OP wasn't confused enough already.  8-)} Bearforce96: For historical reasons, `arr[i]` can also be written as `i[arr]`; the `[]` indexing operator is commutative. **Do not** make use of this fact unless you're entering the [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/).

Comment: @user3164339 Anything that "ends up being" something else is **tautologically** *equivalent* at runtime, because "ends up being" is a sloppy way of saying "is compiled into" or similar. But it's juuuuuuust possible that there will be a *compile-time* efficiency improvement from writing the expression one way versus the other, but it would be on the order of a couple clock-cycles (i.e. immeasurably small or practically immeasurable) and there's no way to predict *which* way would be compiled more quickly (e.g. the form with parens has more tokens, so maybe the lexing stage would be slower).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the key line of your question is:

> Why are there pointers to the parentheses [...] ?

The `*` symbol in C and C++ is somewhat confusingly semantically overloaded. You are correct that it sometimes means "pointer to," as in `int* int_ptr`, where the `*` means "`int_ptr` is a *pointer to* the type to the left of the `*`".

But it *also* means "dereference a pointer to...", which is what's actually going on here. The expressions `(temp + count)` and `(foo + i)` evaluate to pointers-to-`int`s, because adding an int-like type to a pointer value results in that pointer value *offset* by the integer type (i.e., you are calculating the memory address at some distance from the original pointer). The parentheses simply ensure that the addition operations happen before the `*`'s are applied. So `*(temp + count)` is *dereferencing* the pointer value `temp + count`. This means that it evaluates to the integer value stored at the address `temp + count`.

You can eliminate some of the confusion by thinking of the first meaning as *also* indicating a dereference: `int* int_ptr` is equivalent to `int *int_ptr`, i.e., "if you dereference `int_ptr`, you'll get an `int`." This gives an intuitive sense of why `int* int_one, int_two` declares `int_one` as a *pointer to* an `int`, and `int_two` as an `int`-- *not* as a pointer type.